# Proof: How many continuous/bounded functions on $[0,1]$ verify $f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, solution-verification

*Question:*
How many continuous/bounded functions on $[0,1]$ verify $f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

*Answer:*
Thank to @TonyK @Ryszard Szwarc. I think that i found an ever stronger demonstration that prooves that $\exists ! f_0(x)=0 \; s.t. \; f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for all the functions bounded on $[0;1]$.
So i edited my first post.

I/ It's very easy to show that $f_0(x)=0 \; \forall x \in [0;1]$ verifies $0=f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0$

II/ Now by absurd we assume that it exists at least one bounded function $f_1(x)$ that is different to the zero function and that verifies:$f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

1. By assumption, if such function exists that means: $\exists 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \; s.t. f_1(x_1) \neq 0$ (Without loose of generality $f_1(x_1)>0$)
2. Now let's build the two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ as follow: $u_1=x_1; \; u_n=u_{n-1}/2=x_1/2^n$ and $v_1=f_1(x_1); \; v_n=f_1(u_n)=f_1(u_{n-1}/2)$.
3. But let's recall that: $f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow \sqrt{2}f(x)=f(x/2) $. In consequence: $\exists 0 \leq x' \leq 1 \; s.t. \; v_1=(\sqrt{2})f_1(x') \; s.t. \; f_1(x') \neq 0$ and so $v_n={\sqrt{2}}f_1(u_n)={(\sqrt{2})}^nf_1(x') \; $
4. It is obvious that $u_n \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$ and that $v_n \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} \infty$. So we get that $f_1(x)$ is not bounded because it exists a sequence $v_n$ of elements of $f_1(x)$ that goes to infinity!

III/ And because we know from [Weirstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) that all continuous functions are bounded on a closed interval so

Q.E.D.

Is it correct?

Comment: What is II supposed to be proving?

Comment: @MarkSaving That if it exist $0 \leq x_0 \leq 1$  s.t. $f(x_0)=0$ so $f(x)=0$ for every x in [0;1]. (f(x)=the constante function zero). Btw i don't understant how the system of up and down vote of topic work on this site.

Comment: I think you have it backwards: $f(x_n)=\sqrt 2 f(x_{n-1})$, not $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} f(x_{n-1})$. So $f(x_n)$ tends to $\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: @TonyK i don't understand what you re saying because: $y_1=f(x_1)=cste$ and so $y_n=y_1(2)^{(-n/2)}$

Comment: $y_0=f(x_0)=f(1)$. And putting $x=1$ gives $y_1=f(x_1)=f(x/2)=\sqrt 2f(x)=\sqrt 2y_0>y_0$. Continuing in this way, by induction we get $y_n=2^{n/2}y_0$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @TonyK But by my definition of  $y_1=f(x_0/2)*(2)^{-1/2}$ NOT $y_1=f(x_0/2)*(2)^{1/2}$. The sequence $y_n$ is define recursively as follow $y_n=f(x_{n-1}/2)*(2)^{-1/2}$ And it is by definition that $f(x)$ must be equal to $f(x/2)*(2)^{-1/2}$- EDIT:  i'll think more about what you ve said me when i ll have more time thk for your comment.

Comment: @TonyK yes it is clear

Comment: @TonyK Thank to you comment and to Ryszard Szwarc i think that i found a better demonstration that prooves a stronger theorem. I post it in the answer and i have edited my first post, if you have time i will be happy to know if it is correct?

Comment: Now that you have a self-answer (I agree it's a good proof), I'd consider rolling back the question to a version from before you used others' hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M=\displaystyle\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)|.$ Then $$0\le M\le 2^{-1/2}\sup_{0\le x\le {1\over 2}}|f(x)|\le 2^{-1/2}M$$ Hence $M=0,$ i e. $f(x)= 0$ for any $x\in [0,1].$

Continuity is not essential. It suffices to assume that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank for your comment, i think that i found an other proof to this (thk to @TonyK) for bounded function. I posted it in the answer, and i will be happy to know if at your opinion it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @TonyK @Ryszard Szwarc and their comments. I think that i found an ever stronger demonstration that prooves that $\exists ! f_0(x)=0 \; s.t. \; f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for all the functions bounded on $[0;1]$.

I/ It's very easy to show that $f_0(x)=0 \; \forall x \in [0;1]$ verifies $0=f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0$

II/ Now by absurd we assume that it exists at least one bounded function $f_1(x)$ that is different to the zero function and that verifies:$f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

1. By assumption, if such function exists that means: $\exists 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1 \; s.t. f_1(x_1) \neq 0$ (Without loose of generality $f_1(x_1)>0$)
2. Now let's build the two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ as follow: $u_1=x_1; \; u_n=u_{n-1}/2=x_1/2^n$ and $v_1=f_1(x_1); \; v_n=f_1(u_n)=f_1(u_{n-1}/2)$.
3. But let's recall that: $f(x)=f(x/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Rightarrow \sqrt{2}f(x)=f(x/2) $. In consequence: $\exists 0 \leq x' \leq 1 \; s.t. \; v_1=(\sqrt{2})f_1(x') \; s.t. \; f_1(x') \neq 0$ and so $v_n={\sqrt{2}}f_1(u_n)={(\sqrt{2})}^nf_1(x') \; $
4. It is obvious that $u_n \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$ and that $v_n \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} \infty$. So we get that $f_1(x)$ is not bounded because it exists a sequence $v_n$ of elements of $f_1(x)$ that goes to infinity!

III/ And because we know from [Weirstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) that all continuous functions are bounded on a closed interval so

Q.E.D.

Is it correct?

Comment: In my opinion it is correct. Occasionally I  use the proof by contradiction, but only when any other idea does not come to my mind.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems ok especially idea of part III. However it is hard to read due to lack of some kind of order. It suffices to see that function $f$ has to be bounded (certainly it is) since is continuous on compact set. Moreover it is straightforward that $f(0)=0$. Now we claim $$(\forall x\in[0,1])(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}f\Big(\frac{x}{2^n}\Big).$$ The formal proof of the claim can be done by induction but I will leave as that. The final part can be done like that $$(\forall \epsilon>0)(\forall x\in[0,1]) |f(x)|<\epsilon.$$ Indeed let $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in[0,1]$ be fixed. Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough so the  inequality $$\frac{\displaystyle \sup_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)|}{\sqrt{2^n}}<\epsilon.$$ hold. So we have the following $$|f(x)|= \bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}f\Big(\frac{x}{2^n}\Big)\bigg|\le\frac{\displaystyle \sup_{0\le x\le 1}|f(x)|}{\sqrt{2^n}}<\epsilon. $$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary $$f(x)=0$$ for all $x$.